# Python AVL Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I wanted to get an understanding of different data structures and therefore implemented an AVL tree in Python. I hope that some of you might be willing to check it for correctness.

The binary tree base class:

```
"""Binary search tree implementation."""


def delete(node):
    """
    Delete node from tree.

    :param {Node} node: Node to delete.
    """
    parent = node.parent
    if not node.left or not node.right:
        child = node.left or node.right
        if node == parent.left:
            parent.left = child
        else:
            parent.right = child
        if child:
            child.parent = parent
    elif node == parent.left:
        parent.left = node.right
        node.right.parent = parent
        insert(node.right, node.left)
    else:
        parent.right = node.left
        node.left.parent = parent
        insert(node.left, node.right)
    disconnect(node)
    return parent

def disconnect(node):
    """
    Disconnect node from tree.

    :param {Node} node: Node to disconnect.
    """
    node.left = None
    node.parent = None
    node.right = None
    return node

def find(node, key):
    """
    Find node by key.

    :param {Node} node: Current node.
    :param {any} key: Key to find.
    """
    while True:
        if key == node.key:
            return node
        elif key < node.key:
            if not node.left:
                return
            node = node.left
        else:
            if not node.right:
                return
            node = node.right

def in_order(node):
    """
    Return nodes in order.

    :param {Node} node: Node to process.
    """
    nodes = []
    if node:
        nodes.extend(in_order(node.left))
        nodes.append(node)
        nodes.extend(in_order(node.right))
    return nodes

def insert(node, new_node):
    """
    Insert node into tree.

    :param {Node} node: Current node.
    :param {Node} new_node: New node to insert.
    """
    if not node:
        return new_node
    while True:
        if new_node.key == node.key:
            node.data.extend(new_node.data)
            return node
        elif new_node.key < node.key:
            if not node.left:
                node.left = new_node
                break
            node = node.left
        else:
            if not node.right:
                node.right = new_node
                break
            node = node.right
    new_node.parent = node
    return new_node

def show(node):
    """
    Pretty print tree.

    :param {Node} node: Node to start from.
    """
    return "\n".join(_show_recurse(node)[0])

def _show_recurse(node):
    """
    Recursively pretty print (stolen from MIT course).

    :param {Node} node: Current node.
    """
    if not node:
        return [], 0, 0
    label = str(node.key)
    left_lines, left_pos, left_width = _show_recurse(node.left)
    right_lines, right_pos, right_width = _show_recurse(node.right)
    middle = max(right_pos + left_width - left_pos + 1, len(label), 2)
    pos = left_pos + middle // 2
    width = left_pos + middle + right_width - right_pos
    while len(left_lines) < len(right_lines):
        left_lines.append(" " * left_width)
    while len(right_lines) < len(left_lines):
        right_lines.append(" " * right_width)
    if (middle - len(label)) % 2 == 1 and node.parent is not None and \
       node is node.parent.left and len(label) < middle:
        label += "."
    label = label.center(middle, ".")
    if label[0] == ".":
        label = " " + label[1:]
    if label[-1] == ".":
        label = label[:-1] + " "
    lines = [
        " " * left_pos + label + " " * (right_width - right_pos),
        " " * left_pos + "/" + " " * (middle-2) +
        "\\" + " " * (right_width - right_pos)
        ] + [left_line + " " * (width - left_width - right_width) + right_line for left_line, right_line in zip(left_lines, right_lines)]
    return lines, pos, width


class Node():
    """Node class."""

    __slots__ = ["data", "key", "left", "parent", "right"]

    def __init__(self, key, data):
        """
        Initialize new node.

        :param {any} key: Key of the node.
        :param {any} data: Payload to store.
        """
        self.data = [data]
        self.key = key
        self.left = self.parent = self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Retrurn node representation."""
        return "({} => {})".format(self.key, self.data)


class BSTree():
    """Binary-Search-Tree class."""

    __slots__ = ["root"]

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize tree."""
        self.root = None

    def __str__(self):
        """Pretty print tree."""
        if not self.root:
            return "<empty tree>"
        return show(self.root)

    def delete(self, key):
        """
        Delete node from tree.

        :param {any} key: Key of the node to find.
        """
        node = self.find(key)
        if node:
            # root node
            if not node.parent:
                if node.left and node.right:
                    self.root = node.left
                    insert(self.root, node.right)
                else:
                    self.root = node.left or node.right
                return self.root
            delete(node)
            return node

    def find(self, key):
        """
        Find node by key.

        :param {any} key: Key to find.
        """
        return find(self.root, key)

    def in_order(self):
        """Return nodes."""
        return in_order(self.root)

    def insert(self, key, data=None):
        """
        Insert node into tree.

        :param {any} key: Key of the node.
        :param {any} data: Payload to store.
        """
        new_node = Node(key, data)
        if not self.root:
            self.root = new_node
            return self.root
        return insert(self.root, new_node)
```

AVL implementation on top:

```
"""AVL-Tree implementation."""
import bst


def get_height(node):
    """
    Get height for node.

    :param {Node} node: Return height for node.
    """
    return node.height if node else -1

def get_root(node):
    """
    Find root node by walking up the tree.

    :param {Node} node: Node to start from.
    """
    while node.parent:
        node = node.parent
    return node

def rebalance(node):
    """
    Rebalance subtree.

    :param {Node} node: Node to rebalance.
    """
    while node:
        left_height = get_height(node.left)
        right_height = get_height(node.right)
        update_height(node)
        if left_height == right_height + 2:
            if get_height(node.left.left) >= get_height(node.left.right):
                rotate_right(node)
            else:
                rotate_left(node.left)
                rotate_right(node)
        elif right_height == left_height + 2:
            if get_height(node.right.right) >= get_height(node.right.left):
                rotate_left(node)
            else:
                rotate_right(node.right)
                rotate_left(node)
        node = node.parent

def relink_parent(node, child):
    """
    Relink parent node to child.

    :param {Node} parent: Node whose parent to relink.
    :param {Node} child: Child node to relink.
    """
    if child:
        child.parent = node.parent
    if node.parent:
        if node.parent.left == node:
            node.parent.left = child
        else:
            node.parent.right = child

def rotate_left(node):
    """
    Left node rotation.

    :param {Node} node: Node to rotate.
    """
    child = node.right
    relink_parent(node, child)
    # Relink remaining child
    node.right = child.left
    if node.right:
        node.right.parent = node
    # Relink node
    child.left = node
    node.parent = child
    update_height(node)
    update_height(child)

def rotate_right(node):
    """
    Right node rotation.

    :param {Node} node: Node to rotate on.
    """
    child = node.left
    relink_parent(node, child)
    # Relink remaining child
    node.left = child.right
    if node.left:
        node.left.parent = node
    # Relink node
    child.right = node
    node.parent = child
    update_height(node)
    update_height(child)

def update_height(node):
    """
    Update node height.

    :param {Node} node: Return height for node.
    """
    node.height = max(get_height(node.left), get_height(node.right)) + 1


class Node():
    """Class representating an AVL node."""

    __slots__ = ["data", "height", "key", "left", "parent", "right"]

    def __init__(self, key, data=None):
        """
        Create new node.

        :param {any} key: Key to use for operations.
        :param {any} data: Payload to store.
        """
        self.data = [data]
        self.height = 1
        self.key = key
        self.left = self.parent = self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return string representation."""
        return "{} ({} => {})".format(self.height, self.key, self.data)


class AVLTree(bst.BSTree):
    """AVL-Tree class."""

    def delete(self, key):
        """
        Delete node from tree.

        :param {any} key: Key of the node to find.
        """
        node = self.find(key)
        parent = node.parent
        if node:
            # root node
            if not parent:
                if node.left and node.right:
                    self.root = node.left
                    for child in bst.in_order(node.right):
                        bst.disconnect(child)
                        rebalance(bst.insert(self.root, child))
                else:
                    self.root = node.left or node.right
                return self.root
            else:
                # two children
                if node.left and node.right:
                    # get in-order successor (left-most child of right subtree)
                    successor = node.right
                    while successor.left:
                        successor = successor.left
                    parent = successor.parent
                    relink_parent(successor, successor.right)
                    relink_parent(node, successor)
                    successor.left, node.left.parent = node.left, successor
                    successor.right, node.right.parent = node.right, successor
                    bst.disconnect(node)
                # only one child or leaf node
                else:
                    relink_parent(node, node.left or node.right)
                    bst.delete(node)
                rebalance(parent)
            return node

    def insert(self, key, data=None):
        """
        Insert node into tree.

        :param {any} key: Key of the node.
        :param {any} data: Payload to store.
        """
        new_node = Node(key, data)
        if not self.root:
            self.root = new_node
            return self.root
        rebalance(bst.insert(self.root, new_node))
        self.root = get_root(self.root)
        return new_node
```